# "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to protect this computer" inconsistency

Tags: windows, installation, block, ntfs

I am encountering a strange inconsistency with this message.  Basically, we does a Symantec extended validation code signing on our windows product installer.  We had been doing this since end of July (it is not fully automated yet) and we had done more than 50 signings for different products' releases.  The verification process involve:
1. Running signtool /verify option to check that the signing was done properly.
2. I will then manually open the File's properties to double check to be sure.

Yesterday, our tester for another product release noticed a problem on a Windows 2003 and Windows 2008 box and discovered this message from Files' properties.  An internet search quickly points to this NTFS's feature.

However, here are the discrepancies that I am trying to figure out. When I start up a vagrant image running Windows 2012 R2 (64bit) with NTFS system and download this signed installer, I noticed that the "Zone.Identifier" is NOT removed when I do a more < myinstaller.exe:Zone.Identifier; and if I bring up the file's properties, I DON'T see this warning/error about "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to protect this computer".  And therefore during my manual test run, I am okay.

I am trying to identify the difference and looked thru "Local Group Policy" with "Do not preserve zone information in file attachment"; and that was Not Configured.  I also checked the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies, and there is no "Attachements\SaveZoneInformation" setting.  I also checked the browser settings for "trusted site" and etc and found no difference (based on quick manual browsing).  I don't understand why my vagrant image can strip off the "message" (and thus not blocking the file) without stripping the zone id.  Also, I don't understand how come the problem was noticed yesterday and not earlier...  Still trying to sort those out.

I like to find other options beside asking our customers to edit their PCs.  Shouldn't the purpose of a "signed-certificate" is to allow our users to trust the download?

Comment: It isn't very clear how you codesigned your installer.  Most programmers would complain "I spent five hundred bucks on a certificate and it still doesn't work!".  Which is what it takes.

Comment: I don't know how much my company spent on the certificate.  It is signed twice; first with Verisign Class 3 and then with Symantec (sorry about the misspelling previously) extended validation certificate.  We had been doing this since end of July; we must had done this signing more than 40-50 times for different product installers.  This problem came yesterday, so I am still trying to figure out if something had recently changed or if for some incredible reason that someone no one notice this issue before.